# PHP Not validating the dates properly

Tags: php, mysql

i was validating the dates and got to know a bug

in my db the date is stored as `29-09-2021` and when i validate it like

```
$fdate = '01-10-2021';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '".$fdate."'";
$result= $connect->query($sql );
$row= mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

It should give a value because `$fdate` is a date of next month but it gives no result
please help if any need to change db needed i can do

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't store the dates in the database as dates instead of strings?

Comment: Please, make your life easier and store the dates as dates, not as strings.

Comment: @Dharman what you mean can you tell please?

Comment: Do not store them as `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`. Instead use `DATE` or `DATETIME` data type.

Comment: but how it will help me in my code @Dharman

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your questions. Please read the manual if you want to learn more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html When you store dates using the proper data type then you can easily compare dates without any need for conversion or formatting. It prevents mistakes and improves performance.

Comment: Ok Thank you for giving me your time

Answer (score -1):

Try CAST(date AS DATE) >=  CAST('.$date.' AS DATE)